# What is the difference between (onSaveInstanceState) and (android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize")?

Tags: android

I use the one layout file for both landscaper and portrait mode in my app.
First I tried to mange orientation changes using onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState which works but it's needs more work to mange dialog orientations changes, but later I found out that `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`
do the same work which is just a single line. What are the differences between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onSaveInstanceState and android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" are both used to handle the configuration changes, however they are completely different from each other.

they both help you save your  state information, like user input.

onSavedInstanceState is automatically called when the activity is about to be destroyed, so that It's up-to you to save any state in the bundle that your view has. after configuration change, when you activity is destroyed and recreated, in onCreate method you can get those that you saved from savedInstanceState bundle.

android:configChanges tells activity which configuration changes it needs to handle itself. So in that case the activity won't be destroyed and recreated, thus preserving your state information. So this time onConfigurationChanged() method will be called and in that method you can handle all the changes.

so yeah, depending on situation you can use one or another.

Comment: OK, appreciate your help.